# Consistent estimation of discrete probabilities given probabilistic observations

Tags: independence, bernoulli-distribution, consistency

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are Bernoulli distributed. 
When we have observed data, it's clear we can estimate marginal and joint probabilities from counting occurrences. For example, suppose we have the following N=3 observations:

```
X_n  Y_n 
0    0
0    1
1    1
```

We might estimate probabilities as follows:

```
p(X=1) = 1/3,     p(Y=1)=2/3
p(X=1,Y=1)=1/3,   p(X=1,Y=0)=0/3
p(X=0,Y=1)=1/3,   p(X=0,Y=0)=1/3
```

But suppose that each of our observations comes with measurement error, so we instead observe a probability of each variable being 0 or 1:

```
p(X_n=1)  p(Y_n=1) 
  0.1       0.3
  0.2       0.3
  0.7       0.6
```

It would be natural to generalize the formula above, and estimate marginals as follows:
p(X=1) = (0.1+0.2+0.7)/3
p(Y=1) = (0.3+0.3+0.6)/3.
And then one would estimate joint probabilities as follows:

```
p(X=1,Y=1) = (0.1*0.3+0.2*0.3+0.7*0.6)/3
p(X=1,Y=0) = (0.1*0.7+0.2*0.7+0.7*0.4)/3
p(X=0,Y=1) = (0.9*0.3+0.8*0.3+0.3*0.6)/3
p(X=0,Y=0) = (0.9*0.7+0.8*0.7+0.3*0.4)/3
```

What are the conditions under which the above procedure is consistent? It seems to me that procedure for marginals is always consistent by the laws of probability. But it seems to me that the procedure for joint probabilities assumes independence between $X$ and $Y$. Is this intuition correct?

Comment: At a minimum, the probabilities had better be accurate!  In other words, if there's any systematic measurement error, consistency is a hopeless dream.  And don't you mean that your procedure assumes the *measurement errors* for $X$ and $Y$ are independent? Thus, I think we're going to need a clearer account of how measurement error arises and how it is related to the true values of $X$ and $Y.$